# How to always track some certain events with logging module? (python)

Tags: python, logging

This [(howto)](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html)  page shows  level or severity of the events  functions are used to track with logging module.Now I want to always track some event. Yes,I could set level to critical,but it's not used like that. It's used when A serious error, indicating that the program itself may be unable to continue running.
An example will be easier for you to understand what I want:

Set level to INFO

```
self.logger = logging.getLogger(logName)
self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
....
```

Outputs:

```
INFO: Instance 3 (I want this line always on display)
INFO: parameter a is in range
INFO: parameter b is in range
INFO: parameter c is in range
WARNING: VALUE ERROR
```

I want to track WARNING events only,so I set level to WARNING:

```
self.logger = logging.getLogger(logName)
self.logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Outputs:

```
WARNING: VALUE ERROR
```

I tracked the error events indeed,but I missed the Instance event. Thus I won't know under which instance the error happened.

I don't want to set level of Instance event to CRITICAL although it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create another logger object for logging that event you want, and set its level to INFO.
So you end up with self.logger and self.special_event_logger.